# UILocalNotification Alternative for Alarm

Tags: ios, xcode, uilocalnotification

I am developing alarm application and I know that it is not recommended to use UILocalNotification. Using Local Notification I cannot make sound loop for example. Is there any alternatives to UILocalNotification? And which method is fired when notification appears?

Comment: No there is not any alternative to UILocalNotification...

Comment: I don't think that there are good alternatives. I've seen many apps using geoloc to keep app alive in background, and then play sound at the right time. But it sounds dirty :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UILocalNotification * localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

localNotification.fireDate = targetDateTime;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.userInfo = @"Its Morning Time";

 NSString * soundName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"ColorName"];

localNotification.soundName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.wav",soundName];


localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

By using above code we can fire UILocalNotification as alarm & can play your own sound file as a alarm sound.

For playing different different files as a alarm sound you can give user an interface like in UIPickerView in which all Notification sounds names are dispalyed. The selected file become as a alarm sound for the user.

One more thing you can do is by calling a function after one day interval you can choose different sound file and can play as a alarm sound file.

Hope this info help you.